# grails-wkhtmltopdf plugin is not rendering

Tags: grails, wkhtmltopdf

- Grails 3.0.9
- compile "org.grails.plugins:wkhtmltopdf:1.0.0.RC3"
- application.yml already has pdf: application/pdf
- command line works %> wkhtmltopdf www.google.com myhomepage.pdf

I am trying to generate PDF in controller/action. But it renders the template rather than generate PDF.

```
render( filename:"File bla.pdf",
view:"/sr/pdfGenerator",
model:[bla:bla],
header:"",
footer:"",
marginLeft:20,
marginTop:35,
marginBottom:20,
marginRight:20,
headerSpacing:10)
```

If i comment out render() from action it will generate empty PDF.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the introduced because of a change after Grails 3.0.7. Please see developer response in [GitHub](https://github.com/rlovtangen/grails-wkhtmltopdf/issues/15#issuecomment-168835476)